# Swift - Google Ad Mob SDK 7 - showing only in simulator

Tags: ios, swift, admob

I try to integrate Admob interstitial in my app and I have a problem - ads show only in simulator.

I use the following code

```
class MenuViewController: UIViewController, GADInterstitialDelegate {

var interstitial: GADInterstitial?

override func viewDidLoad() {

    loadInterstitial()
}  

func loadInterstitial() {

    var request = GADRequest()
    request.testDevices = ["here is test device id"]

    interstitial = GADInterstitial(adUnitID: "here is ID")
    interstitial!.delegate = self
    interstitial!.loadRequest(GADRequest())

}

override func viewDidAppear(animated: Bool) {

    showAd()

}

func showAd() {

    if !adsRemoved {

        if self.interstitial!.isReady {

            println("interstitial isReady")

            self.interstitial!.presentFromRootViewController(self)

        } else {
            println("intersitial notReady")
        }

    }

    self.interCount = 1

  } 
}
```

on device it is always printing in console "intersitial notReady"
I trued both cases with request.testDevices and without. Both are not working on physical device, but shows in simulator.

also I have

```
    func interstitialDidFailToReceiveAdWithError (
    interstitial: GADInterstitial,
    error: GADRequestError) {
        println("interstitialDidFailToReceiveAdWithError: %@" + error.localizedDescription)
}
```

but it is not working

Where can be the problem ?

Comment: You're trying to present your interstitial before it has had a chance to load. Check my answer [here](http://stackoverflow.com/a/32459755/2108547).

Comment: but why it works in simulator then ? both simulator and device have same internet connection

Comment: Being on the same network and having the same hardware capabilities are two different things.

Comment: it have worked on device! You are great, thanks a lot!